# NVCC warning about [[deprecated]]: "attribute does not apply to any entity"

Tags: cuda, c++14, deprecated, nvcc

If I compile the following piece of code:

```
using foo [[deprecated]] = char;
```

with nvcc v10.2.89, and with `-std=c++14`, I get:

```
warning: attribute does not apply to any entity
```

But this doesn't happen with `-std=c++11`. Why am I getting this warning at all? This seems to be valid C++14.

[See this on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bxf4PM65q).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug in that version of NVCC. With CUDA 11.x  versions of NVCC, this [doesn't seem to happen](https://godbolt.org/z/8c84W7qE1). It seems you'll need to upgrade, or have your users upgrade.